# How to determine resource work availability in PSI

Tags: c#, ms-project-server-2013, psi

I am using PSI interface of MS Project Server 2013 via Microsoft.SharePoint.Client context.

I need to get number or hours available for specific resource in specific date.

For example, Resource1 has current max units 100%. I set 8h work day, and it means that Resource1 has 8h every work day. I set Resource1 plan work 2h to today. So I need to get max avaliable hours for today: 8h - 2h = 6h.

```
//open project context
ProjectContext projContext;
projContext = new ProjectContext(pwaPath);

//load enterprise resource
projContext.Load(projContext.EnterpriseResources);
projContext.ExecuteQuery();

//get first resource
EnterpriseResource resource = projContext.EnterpriseResources[0];

//what should I do next?
```

Does exist any way to get this estimate without manual calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Parse("09.04.2015");
        DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Parse("12.28.2016");
        var plan = checkoutProj.GetResourcePlan(dtStart, dtEnd, TimeScale.Days);

        projContext.Load(plan.Assignments);
        projContext.ExecuteQuery();

        DateTime dttest = DateTime.Parse("8.28.2016");
        var assgn = plan.Assignments[0].Intervals.GetByStart(dttest);

        projContext.Load(plan.Assignments[0].Intervals);
        projContext.Load(plan.Assignments[1].Intervals);
        projContext.Load(assgn);
        projContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

**assgn.Duration** gives you workload for specific day.